# How to colour html table which is stored in SQL varchar variable

Tags: html, sql-server

I have stored procedure which convert sql query into html table, example of use:

```
DECLARE @Html varchar(1000)
SET @html = dbo.queryIntoHtmlTable 'select * from dbo.Users'
```

and @html looks  like following

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr style="background-color: black"><th bgcolor="#5D7B9D">USER</th><th bgcolor="#5D7B9D">SUCCESS</th><th bgcolor="#5D7B9D">DATE</th></tr>
 </tr><tr><td>USER1</td><td>YES</td><td>2016/01/07</td>
 </tr><tr><td>USER2</td><td>NO</td><td>2016/01/20</td>
 </tr><tr><td>USER3</td><td>NO</td><td>2016/01/15</td>
</table>
```

I've allready managed how to colour field values with 'YES' or 'NO'

```
 REPLACE(@Html,'<TD>YES</TD>','<TD style=background-color:black>YES</TD>')
```

But how can I colour fields of table depending on values in fields  ??

For example

if **value < 5** then colour red , **value > 5** then blue.
Or **valueA > 5 and valueB < 10** then...colour field with green

Comment: Do you want to do it Server or Client site?

Comment: on the server, with somekind of SQL procedure